# Invalid column name with alias and HAVING

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am adding a few columns and giving them alias. Then I want to display only the rows where the result of the addition is greater than certain amount:

```
SELECT (COALESCE(col1, 0.0) + COALESCE(col, 0.0)) as total, id, email
FROM table
HAVING total > 20
```

but I get `Invalid column name 'total'`.

I thought I can use alias and `HAVING` together, so why is it invalid?

Comment: [Logical Query Processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) SELECT is after HAVING

Comment: I think you will have to make a subquery

Comment: Why are you using a `HAVING` when you have no aggregation?

Comment: *"I thought I can use alias and `HAVING` together"* You thought wrong; the only place you can reference a column by its alias in the same scope is in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: thanks everyone, I wasn't sure why it didn't work so I thought the addition is sort of aggregation. Now I will need to redo the query, perhaps with a subquery as mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the two columns like this:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(col1, 0.0) + COALESCE(col, 0.0) AS total, id, email
FROM table
WHERE COALESCE(col1, 0.0) + COALESCE(col, 0.0) > 20
```

Aggregation (and therefore also the HAVING clause) is only required if you are adding values of different rows.

Note that the SELECT part is actually executed **after** the WHERE part. So, the WHERE part does not know the aliases given in the SELECT part and you must repeat the expression.

You could also use a sub-query to calculate the sum instead, but this seems to complicated for this simple case and can potentially slow down the query.

Comment: that was really simple and worked. Is there any performance-hit when you do the arithmetic operation twice?

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a sub query for this, you can simply repeat the expression in the *where* clause.

If repeating the expression is abhorrent you can `apply` it and re-use it.

You mention *addition* but there is no valid addition in your example query (nor aggregation), although if there were the same applies, perhaps the following was your intention?

```
SELECT tot.total, id, email
FROM table t
cross apply(values(COALESCE(col1, 0) + COALESCE(col, 0)))tot(Total)
where tot.Total > 20;
```

Comment: `(COALESCE(col1, 0.0), COALESCE(col, 0.0))` isn't actually a valid expression in the `SELECT`, so i'm not sure what the OP wants from that. In your query this would generate an error as you define your `VALUES` table construct to have 2 columns but only alias 1.

Comment: True, I copied the OP's line verbatim. Probably it should be + instead of , - so I amended above to at least be valid.

Comment: You are correct I had a typo, it's `+`, updated the post